# Difference between Pan-Frying and Searing

Tags: frying

What exactly is the difference between pan-frying and searing? They both use the same principles -- high heat, oil, flip once or twice -- and they both create the same result, namely that wonderful golden crust.

Is there a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pan-Frying is a complete cooking technique. When something has been 'pan-fried' it is done and ready to serve.

Searing is an incomplete process, a step in a larger process. Searing can happen before roasting, braising or other finishing method. It is even good to sear before marinading.

Comment: If that's true, how are the techniques different? I cannot identify a clear difference between the two.

Comment: Also, searing does not have to be done in a pan. It can also be done on the grill, in a griddle pan or even over an open flame. To sear something just means to brown/caramelize its surface. Since a pan is the most convenient method, most searing is done in a pan.

Comment: @ashes: they're not. Simply you don't say *I pan-fried the roast*, but rather *I seared the roast before putting it in the oven*.

Comment: @ashes, the "clear difference" is time and motive. Because searing is "incomplete" it is merely a "surface treatment". Whether done in a pan or on grill. Searing is done 'quickly' and only affects the surface. (thanks to Henrik & nico for adding clarity to my answer)

Comment: I disagree with "Searing is an incomplete process".  For some things (like [Pittsburgh Rare steaks](http://www.cooksinfo.com/edible.nsf/pages/pittsburghrare) ), it is the only process.

Comment: @jwernerny, that would depend on your definition of "done". I am not sure I would agree that a steak which has only been seared is "done", ready to eat.